# Closing Batch File

Tags: batch-file

I wrote a batch file, which has 3 .bat file running in background. I have another batch file which has 3 .bat file, which is used to stop those .bat file which ran in first batch file. All this is working fine, but after stopping those .bat files, first batch file's command window is not closing. I gave 'exit' to both the batch file which I wrote.
Please help me in this.

Comment: Can you post the actual batch files? Or something equivalent.

Comment: were you doing XAMPP related stuff ... because I am having the same problem with XAMPP batch files.

Answer (score 3):

You could try starting the other batch files with

```
CMD /C
```

alternatively when they are supposed to close, you could try closing them by name directly from the other batch file:

```
taskkill /F /IM batchname.bat
```

Comment: Yeah, I think taskkill using the window name would be a good way to work around this issue if it actually is a problem.  Hard to know any other way to do it without seeing his code though...

Answer (score 1):

Are you using

```
call batchfile.bat
```

to run the batchfiles? If not, the flow will be unexpected.

Comment: i am using start /b batchfile.bat

Comment: Even while testing with 4 simple batch files, this yields to strange errors. I think you shouldn't call batchfiles like this, it seems to confuse cmd.

Answer (score 1):

if you could convert it to .exe, with Bat-To-Exe-Converter, you could use:

```
tskill [program]
```

Like if you want to close a batch file which is converted called 'helloworld.exe':

```
tskill helloworld
```

What you also could use,
is:

```
tskill cmd
```

And do this a few times. It will close 1 commdandprompt/time.

Answer (score 1):

I do a delayed close with some of my batch scripts this way:

```
FOR /l %%a in (30,-1,1) do (TITLE %TITLE% -- Closing in %%as&ping -n 2 -w 1 127.0.0.1>NUL)
EXIT /B 0
```